# The "famous" Element type is invalid Error

Tags: reactjs

This morning I tried to put all my components in a css grid. But I got an error.

I have identified the component that is causing the problem but even after trying all the solutions founded on Stack Overflow (which provide

**Here the Error**

```
*Element type is invalid:
expected a string (for built-in components)
or a class/function (for composite components)
but got: undefined. 
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

**Here the (naughty) component**

```
import React  from "react";
import {ResponsiveContainer,AreaChart,Area,CartesianGrid,XAxis,YAxis,Tooltip,Legend} from "recharts";

const ErrorChart = ({data}) =>{


return (
    <div  className="chart-container" style={{ width: '40%', height: 300 }}>
    <ResponsiveContainer>
      <AreaChart
        data={data}
        margin={{
          top: 10, right: 30, left: 0, bottom: 0,
        }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis dataKey="time" />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <Area type="monotone" dataKey="number" stroke="#8884d8" fill="#8884d8" />
      </AreaChart>
      <Legend/>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  </div>
  );

}
export default ErrorChart
```

Comment: Cant see anything wrong with this syntax wise, so it's possible theres something wrong with your data? Maybe one of your dataKey's doesn't exist in your data somewhere

Comment: @DavinTryon isn't Legend self colsing itself?

Comment: Oh i  put it in the AeraChart tag and it work just fine thanj you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trials, to remove the error, it seems that `Legend` must be outside the `ResponsiveContainer`:

```
<div className="chart-container" style={{ width: "40%", height: 300 }}>
      <ResponsiveContainer>
        <AreaChart
          data={data}
          margin={{
            top: 10,
            right: 30,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0
          }}
        >
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
          <XAxis dataKey="time" />
          <YAxis />
          <Tooltip />
          <Area
            type="monotone"
            dataKey="number"
            stroke="#8884d8"
            fill="#8884d8"
          />
        </AreaChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
      <Legend />
    </div>
```

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-swartz-bf8dk)

Comment: It also can be in the AreaChart tag

Comment: Is this answer perhaps outdated? Official docs show legend inside the container for a `LineChart`: https://recharts.org/en-US/examples

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a `{' '}` added by VsCode right before the closing `</ResponsiveContainer>` that was causing this error.